# How do cross-compilie on mips without error?

Tags: c, mips, cross-compiling

I want to cross compile for MIPS. I am compiling this simple hello world:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("HELLO WORLD\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I compile it's so: `mips-gcc e.c -static -o hello`  .

It is `hello: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped`

uname -a on MIPS system is:

`Linux RT-AC1200 2.6.36 #1 Thu Mar 15 11:18:53 CST 2018 mips GNU/Linux`

However, when I'm trying to start hello, I'm getting:

`./hello: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("`

I tried to compile with different MIPS cross compilers(including gcc-mips-linux-gnu), however always I get this error. What do I do wrong? How to compile right ?

Comment: Is the `file hello` posted from compiler machine or target machine?

Comment: @Mathieu, yes, it's: hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (ARM), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped

Comment: @Rainbow: "yes" to which of the two alternatives?!

Comment: Why do you present different results, MIPS and ARM?

Comment: ohh, upps. That was another binary. However, the error is still here with binary: hello: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped   . Checked on a compiler machine. On a target machine is no file command and no way to download it